# Find RayCast Vector and move away from it in Godot

Tags: math, vector, 2d, godot

I am making a game in Godot and I want one of my enemies to move away from the ground when it detects a collision with RayCasts.
I set up my RayCasts like this:
[image]
I tried using this code:

```
for i in dodge.get_children():
    if i.is_colliding():
        var velocity = Vector2().rotated(deg2rad(i.rotation_degrees))
        move_and_collide(velocity * -charge_speed * delta)
```

Where dodge holds all the RayCasts and I go through all its children and check for collisions. I then tried rotating the Vector2 by the rotation of the RayCasts, since that is how I rotated them instead of using Cast To, and tried moving it by that Vector, but it didn't work. It didn't even move in the wrong direction. It didn't move at all.

How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
var velocity = Vector2().rotated(deg2rad(i.rotation_degrees))
```

Here you create a new Vector with `Vector2()`. Which is equivalent to `Vector2(0.0, 0.0)`.

When you rotate `Vector2(0.0, 0.0)`, regardless of the angle, it will remain `Vector2(0.0, 0.0)`.

As a result `velocity` will be `Vector2(0.0, 0.0)`.

Then in this line you scale `velocity`:

```
move_and_collide(velocity * -charge_speed * delta)
```

If you multiply zero, I mean `Vector2(0.0, 0.0)`, by any number it is still `Vector2(0.0, 0.0)`.

And so it will move according to `Vector2(0.0, 0.0)`, i.e. not at all.

---

So you need to change that starting `Vector2()`. It could be `Vector.RIGHT` or `Vector.UP`, or more likely `Vector.DOWN`. How do you know? Well, it is the direction of the `RayCast2D` if you don't rotate them.

---

Or, alternatively, you could use `cast_to` also. I believe it is like this:

```
var velocity = i.global_transform.basis_xform(i.cast_to).normalized()
```

Using `basis_xform` should apply the rotation (and any skewing), but not the translation. I also added `normalized` because I don't know if the result will be an unit vector, so it is to make sure it is.